# editor style css and page template with and without sidebar

Tags: theme-development, css

I have two page templates in my custom theme. Full width template and Default template. Full width template does not have side bar and is of width 980px. While default template is having sidebar on right side and is of 700px width for content.

I have used editor-style.css to provide content width of 980px.

Problem is when user select default template content in editor is 980px wide, which i want to make 700px.

When user selects full width template content area in editor should be 980px wide.

As this is part of editor-style.css, i am not able to make it conditional based on template selection.

Can any one provide a hook or way to change content width in editor based on template selection.

I also prefer JS solution , but am not able to find tinymce setting for that.

Thanks in advance for any help......

Comment: Are you reffering to page templates that is used in backend or frontend

Comment: @PieterGoosen i am refering to "Page" template that are defined in theme by comment on top "Template Name: Full Width Template" and appears in edit.php for pages to be selected.